# How can I set the Type of a Defect using the VersionOne.SDK.NET.ObjectModel

Tags: .net, sdk, versionone

I am using the VersionOne.SDK.NET.ObjectModel to create defects in VersionOne for our team.
https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.NET.ObjectModel/

But there is now a requirement to set the type on a defect.

The Type property of the Defect class is read-only.

*public IListValueProperty Type { get { return GetListValue("Type"); } }*

I have previously modified the source code of the object model to extend it with set properties but in this case I haven't been able to get it to work.

In addition, has anyone been able to retrieve the list of possible defect type strings that are available for a project ?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of available Defect types can be found with this URL query:

```
http://{server}/{instance}/rest-1.v1/Data/DefectType
```

One you have the OID of the DefectType value, and you know the OID number of the Defect that you want to update, you can issue an HTTP POST request with a URL like this:

```
http://{server}/{instance}/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect/1234
```

With an XML payload like this:

```
<Asset>
    <Attribute name="Type" act="set">DefectType:181</Attribute>
</Asset>
```

Note that VersionOne Object Models (.NET and Java) were sunset in the Spring 2014 release, but the source code remains available in GitHub. If you prefer to use a wrapper for the REST API calls, check out the [.NET SDK (APIClient)](http://v1appcatalog.azurewebsites.net/app/index.html#/Details/VersionOne.SDK.NET.APIClient).

Comment: Thanks acey.   That approach gives you the available defect through the REST API (I will use that method as a fallback).  Any idea if I can do the same through the .NET object model ?  Also, any idea how I set the defect type on a defect preferably using object model but if not using REST ?  Cheers.

Comment: Updated the answer to address your specific question. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks again Acey.  That is a good way of doing this via REST.   I can use your REST approach to access the various defect type definitions and I have now found how to use the object model (rather than REST) to set the type on a defect using the following code....string strDefectType = "crash/wrong results";
defect.Type.CurrentValue = strDefectType;